# how to configure GN (Google's generate-ninja)/Ninja to use different clang toolchain

Tags: clang, glibc, clang++, ninja, gn

I'm using [GN](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/) and `Ninja` to build a Chromium project but encountered the following error:

```
$  ninja -C out/Release/

...
...

../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ~/client/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6)
```

The reason being it uses the prebuilt clang tooling that comes with the project, however I'm on CentOS 7 and the pinned version of glibc is `GLIBC_2.17`, and I do have a separate clang tooling which doesn't require `GLIBC_2.18`, the question is how do I configure `GN` or `ninja` to not use the prebuilt clang that comes with the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/clang.md), after `gn gen` command, one can override the llvm toolchain location by editing the `clang_base_path` parameter in the `args.gn` file.